# Restoring a HDD backup image from the Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, dd, disk-image

I want to restore a HDD image I have to my laptop's HDD while booted off the Ubuntu Live CD.

The laptop's HDD is unformatted and has no partitions.

I expected this to work:

```
$ sudo dd if=/path/to/backup.img of=/dev/sda
```

But I'm told

```
dd: opening `/dev/sda': Permission denied.
```

What gives?

Comment: Are you sure there are no partitions? Check back with `sudo fdisk -l` and `mount`, maybe something got mounted 'by accident'.

Comment: @Bobby Yeah - I got it working, see my answer, but don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. Doing a `su` first worked. Why's this?

```
$ sudo su
# dd if=/path/to/backup.img of=/dev/sda
```